# Get first and last values for a range

Tags: google-spreadsheets

Say I have a range, A1:A27, and that range has a mix of empty and non empty values, I would like two functions: one to get the first non-empty value in the range, and one to get the Last non-empty value in the range like so.

```
=First(A1:A27)
=Last(A1:A27)
```

The ranges will just be 1 dimensional arrays.

I am going to have to do a lot of instances of this in my sheet, so app scripts won't be usable due to inefficiencies.

How would you write these functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use this to find the first non empty value in the range:

```
=INDEX(A1:A27, MATCH(TRUE, A1:A27<>"", 0))
```

And we could use this to find the last non empty value in the range:

```
=INDEX(A1:A27, MAX(IF(A1:A27<>"", ROW(A1:A27))))
```

Answer (score 0):

### XMATCH Function

The [XMATCH function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12406049?hl=en) has an advantage over MATCH for this application because it supports first-to-last and last-to-first searches.

```
# Syntax 
=XMATCH(search_key, lookup_range, [match_mode], [search_mode])
```

### XMATCH Examples

First value syntax is similar to MATCH except **`exact_match=0`** is default so can be omitted.

```
# First Value 
=INDEX(A1:A27, XMATCH(TRUE, A1:A27<>""))      
=ROW(INDEX(A1:A27, XMATCH(TRUE, A1:A27<>"")))  // Returns Row #
```

XMATCH supports last-to-first searching by specifying **`search_mode=-1`**

```
# Last Value 
=INDEX(A1:A27, XMATCH(TRUE, A1:A27<>"",,-1))
=ROW(INDEX(A1:A27, XMATCH(TRUE, A1:A27<>"",,-1)))  // Returns Row #
```